# ASP.NET MVC Route with values before the controller and no trailing slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

This is probably a simple question but I just can't get it to work.

I've got this route specified in my RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DefaultSiteRoute",
    url: "{accountid}/{hostname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, accountid = UrlParameter.Optional, hostname = UrlParameter.Optional  }
);
```

And it works fine for a url like this

> /123456/www.test.com/

or this

> /123456/www.test.com/Controller/Action

but it can't cope with this

> /123456/www.test.com

I get an IIS 404

What is stranger is if I call `Url.Action` for that route with the default Controller and Action (ie Home/Index) it creates a url without a trailing slash, which it then doesn't recognise.  I really need it to work with and without the trailing slash.

Comment: Do you need trailing slash in all links?

Comment: I don't *need* it, but given that the `Url.Action` method generates a link without the slash it's going to be a problem

Comment: What happens if you make {action} parameter optional?

Comment: @CodeART giving it a default value (`Index`) should already make it "optional".

Comment: @HenkMollema that is correct, all parameters in that route are optional, but 2 have default values specified

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is ASP.net 4.0 doesn't route URLs that ends with an extension to MVC. They do this in order to speed up requests to static files. [See this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/01/asp-net-4-0-enables-routing-of-extensionless-urls-without-impacting-static-requests.aspx)

What you can do:

1) Configure UrlRoutingModule to route all managed and un-managed requests (default is only route managed requests).

Drawback: May be bad for performance.

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <modules>
>      <remove name ="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
>       <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="runtimeVersionv4.0" />
>     </modules>
> <system.webServer>
> ```

2) Configure to handle .com, .net. org etc extensions

Drawback: Feels like a hack.

> ```
>    <system.webServer>
>        <handlers>
>           <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
>            type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler, 
>                  System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
>                  Culture=neutral, 
>                  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>                  path="*.com"
>                  verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"/>
> ```

Comment: Option 1 works great with one small addition, you need to add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` to the modules tag. otherwise, that's it.  I completely forgot that it would be interpreting the .com as an extension, good call!

Comment: Option 1 without setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true works in IIS Express. Didn't test with IIS though.