# MVC Custom RouteHandler not firing for files

Tags: vb.net, mef, asp.net-mvc-5, iroutehandler

I have the following code to register a route with my custom routehandler:

```
 routes.Add(New Route(path & "/{assembly}/{*resource}", New RouteValueDictionary(), New RouteValueDictionary(New With { _
             Key .assembly = AssemblyName _
            }), New EmbeddedContentRouteHandler(PluginAssembly, AssemblyName & "." & path)))
```

This allows me to access embedded resources in a compiled DLL for example: /Content/PluginAssemblyName/File.name

In MVC 3 and 4 the ProcessRequest function fires each time, but from MVC 5 it doesn't, it only fires when I specify a directory, which will obviously give me a null reference exception because I am looking for files, not directories (denominated, obviously, by . as a file should)

I've tried excluding .css and .js to try and see if my custom routehandler will fire, nothing. Testing this in the MVC 4 project, works perfectly.

Starting to tear my hair out.

Any ideas why the RouteHandler won't fire in MVC 5, but does in MVC 4 and 3?

(This is a Pluggable MVC project using MEF that I've brought to MVC 5 piece by piece since the upgrade path didn't pan out too well)

Comment: Its probably the same cause and solution to the question that I answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972092/asp-net-mvc-route-with-values-before-the-controller-and-no-trailing-slash/19978599#19978599

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot of sense, I guess I was never on .NET 4.0 on my MVC project even though it was targetting it? Please add your answer referencing the answered question in your comment here so I can mark it

Comment: The IIS or web.config configuration was probably still on MVC3. I will add my answer if it did solve your problem :)

Comment: It solved the issue of the original question, yes. Now it appears I can't access the embedded resource of the DLL, that's entirely seperate though (Unless you have an idea why that's happening too, lol)

Comment: hehehe, reminder to check "EmbeddedResource" as build action on new projects... not that THAT helped, but meh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting ASP.net 4, it will not intercept URLs that end with an extension.
Follow the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972092/asp-net-mvc-route-with-values-before-the-controller-and-no-trailing-slash/19978599#19978599) to revert to the old behaviour.

and don't forgot to add this line in your route configuration if you want to intercept existing files.

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```