# .NET MVC routing (ignore file extension)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to set up a proxy page for Azure Blob Storage.

I want all requests that match `/^MyArea\/Asset\/.*$/` to route to the MyArea.IndexController.AssetAction.

```
public class MyAreaAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "MyArea_assets",
            "MyArea/Asset/{resource}",
            new { controller = "Index", action = "Asset"}
        );
    }
}
```

I will then do the following in the Action.

```
public ActionResult Asset(string resource)
{
    // fetch content from Azure Blob Storage and return it.
    return Content(/* some conent */);
}
```

This works okay if the request is `/MyArea/Asset/foo` but doesn't if its `/MyArea/Asset/foo.txt`.

How can I get the router to ignore the file extension and pass everything to a single action?

--

The extension can be anything .txt, .js, .json etc. I still want the JsonResult overloads to work elsewhere in the app.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972092/asp-net-mvc-route-with-values-before-the-controller-and-no-trailing-slash/19978599#19978599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Comment: I've done this in the Area web.config and it doesn't work. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Is it in your top level web.config?